# c# Oracle SQL statement wildcard

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I am attempting to use a wildcard (%) in C# with oracle. A regular SQL line works fine, but the wildcard returns nothing. The data in the Oracle DB looks like

A1+52345234
A1+88778686

I have commented out the queries I have tried, that do not work. Not sure why, because I can copy the line from debug directly into an sqlplus line, and it works fine. It just doesn't work from C#

Is there a trick to using wildcards with Oracle? I keep getting "Nothing returned"

using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "User Id=" + login + ";Password=" + password + ";Data Source=localhost/" + dbname;
con.Open();
//string sql = "select my_public_id from patient_public_id where my_public_id like 'A%+%' ";
//string sql = "select my_public_id from patient_public_id where my_public_id like 'A" + (char)37 + "+" + (char)37 + "' ";
//string sql = "select my_public_id from patient_public_id where my_public_id like 'A" + "'%'" + "+" + "'%'" + "' ";
OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds);

if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Nothing returned");
```

Comment: I also tried assigning "'A%+%'" to a string variable and using that, still returns nothing.

Comment: Step 1 - put C# to the side. Open Oracle tooling (TOAD or whatever). Get the SQL working there. Once you have it working, come here and share the SQL that worked. Until then, this isn't a C# problem.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are pointed at the right database?

Comment: Does `select my_public_id from patient_public_id` in your C# work?

Comment: What is the value of `ds.Tables.Count`?

Comment: You are right, I tried it in TOAD, and it also does not work there.

Comment: Maybe remove `Not sure why, because I can copy the line from debug directly into an sqlplus line, and it works fine.` then. ;)

Comment: ds.Tables.Count returns zero

Comment: Cool - let us know when you have the SQL fixed and we'll assist on the C# side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229026/discussion-between-d-haskins-and-mjwills).

Answer (score 0):

It was working, problem was I manually added the entries to the DB I was searching for, but did not commit them. lol.